# spring rest dynamically exclude Object properties from serialization

Tags: spring, serialization, jackson, fasterxml, spring-restcontroller

i want to exclude specific properties of spring rest response body. after hours of googling around i found this: http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/filtering_json_feeds_from_spring due to its date i like to ask if there is something more up-to-date for jackson and or fasterxml. JsonView doesnt fit my requirements as i need to have such case covered:

if A is the set of all my attributes: one time i need to expose B with B ⊂ A. another time C with C ⊂ A. And B ∩ C != ∅

this would cause complex view declarations as well as annotating every class and might not be possible as well in some cases. so what i would like to do is something similar to this:

```
@RequestMapping("/test1")
@JsonIgnoreProperties( { "property1"})
public TestObject test1(HttpRequest request){
    return new TestObject();
}

@RequestMapping("/test2")
@JsonIgnoreProperties( { "property2"})
public TestObject test1(HttpRequest request){
    return new TestObject();
}
```

with output:

```
{property2:ipsum,property3:dolor}

{property1:lorem,property3:dolor}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion [Jackson View](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) is what you need.

You have to define three interfaces which should cover all properties:

1. Public - all common properties.
2. A - properties which belong to set A.
3. B - properties which belong to set B.

Example interfaces:

```
  class Views {
            static class Public { }
            static class A extends Public { }
            static class B extends Public { }
  }
```

Assume that your `POJO` class looks like this:

```
class TestObject {
            @JsonView(Views.A.class) String property1;
            @JsonView(Views.B.class) String property2;
            @JsonView(Views.Public.class) String property3;
  }
```

Now, your controller should contain below methods with annotations:

```
@RequestMapping("/test1")
@JsonView(Views.B.class)
public TestObject test1(HttpRequest request){
    return new TestObject();
}

@RequestMapping("/test2")
@JsonView(Views.A.class)
public TestObject test2(HttpRequest request){
    return new TestObject();
}
```

All of this I has created without testing. Only by reading documentation but it should work for you. I am sure that similar solution worked for me once.

Comment: hm.. i see so i have to annotate everything even the related object classes with correct jsonviews thought it might be possible with just controller annotation

Comment: Have you tried given solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: ok got it working for thoose having problems check that you use daterxml and not jackson for newest spring version (jackson didnt work for me)